# Чи правильно вживати "з родзинкою" щодо предметів/явищ?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, фразеологізми

"*З родзинкою*" (ймовірно, від <sub>рос.</sub> "*с изюминкой*") — так кажуть про те/того, хто чимось відрізняється від інших, є особливим.

СУМ-11 не знає [*родзинку*](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodzynka) в однині, але знає [*родзинки*](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodzynky) й [*ізюминку*](http://sum.in.ua/s/izjumynka) — що те, що інше позначає суше́ний виноград.

Словник Кримського-Єфремова, містить [переносне значення](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on):

> - С изюминкой (перен.) – з жи́вчиком, з пе́рчиком.
> - Без -ки – без жи́вчика, без пе́рчика.

Я собі слабо уявляю, що так можна сказати **не** про людину ("*крамниця з перчиком*" <sub>?</sub>).

Словник сталих виразів Виргана-Пилинської [це підтверджує](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=7&highlight=on):

> - Женщина с изюминкой – принадна (зваблива) жінка.
> - Человек с изюминкой (разг.) – людина з живчиком (з перчиком).

Маємо явний сексуальний підтекст ([*racy*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/racy) <sub>?</sub>).

І лише в СУМ-20 проникає [*ізюминка*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=38852&page=1215) <sub>(*родзинка* ще в процесі написання)</sub> про все взагалі:

> Головна ізюминка зоологічного парку – 11 тисяч гектарів цілинного степу, який ніколи не знав плуга (із журн.)

Чи не відбулася тут нехороша мутація? Чи коректно так писати про явища чи предмети? Може, краще заміняти на *особливість*, *унікальність* чи інший?

Answer (score 4):

Щодо фразеологізму "з родзинкою", вважаю, що в такому значенні ним почали послуговуватися завдяки впливу російської мови, це підтверждує навіть СУМ, не фіксуючи слово в однині. У СУМі безліч таких прикладів, була свого часу політика зближення мов, але чомусь виявилося, що українська та білоруська зближалися до російської...

Але з часом мова змінюється і якщо в 20 сторіччі вислів "з родзинкою" був не дуже поширений і його переважно брали в лапки,

> Такий же, "з родзинкою", сюжет, раптова, неочікувана розв'язка притаманна багатьом творам письменника і становить одну з особливостей його сюжетно-композиційних принципів. (1997, Василь Поп, "Творчість Михайла Томчанія")

то сьогодні деякі письменники та перекладачі взяли його до свого арсеналу:

> Двокімнатна хрущовка перепланована з родзинкою — стіна між передпокоєм і вітальнею знесена, тож, варто ввійти, бачиш дальню стіну вітальні з тим правдивим дзеркалом, що воно дивиться на тебе просто з порога. (Люко Дашвар, "На запах м'яса")
>
> Потрібна родзинка. Ось цією [родзинкою](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?C21COM=2&I21DBN=UJRN&P21DBN=UJRN&IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD=1&Image_file_name=PDF/Mysu_2013_13_41.pdfBT3nENae4FUvhJy-A&cad=rjt) і стає некомерційна, творча, 
>   часто  незрозуміла  робота. (Олексій Роготченко)

Моя думка, якщо без "родзинки"  ніяк — можете вжити, але тричі подуймате, адже до 21 сторіччя наші митці слова обходились без неї...